# How to identify what polymer-cli version installed on my computer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-cli

How can i identify what polymer-cli version installed on my computer ?

I mean to say when we want to know the version of npm-cli and bower-cli etc we do

`npm -v`
 `bower -v`
 `gulp -v`

is there is any command or something to get polymer-cli version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out my self it is

`polymer --version`